# All CPAN mirrors are not working in CPAN configuration?

Tags: perl, configuration, centos6, cpan

I am trying to install CPAN and configure it on Centos 6.

I am getting this message in configuration:

> CPAN.pm requires configuration, but most of it can be done
>   automatically. If you answer 'no' below, you will enter an interactive
>   dialog for each configuration option instead. Would you like to
>   configure as much as possible automatically? [yes]

I chose yes, then I am prompted with this message:

> Autoconfigured everything but 'urllist'.
>   Now you need to choose your
>   CPAN mirror sites.  You can let me pick mirrors for you, you can
>   select them from a list or you can enter them by hand. Would you like
>   me to automatically choose some CPAN mirror sites for you? (This means
>   connecting to the Internet) [yes]

I also chose yes to get that message:

> Trying to fetch a mirror list from the Internet Fetching with LWP:
>   http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY Fetching with LWP:
>   http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY.gz Fetching with LWP:
>   ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY Fetching with LWP:
>   ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY.gz Fetching with Net::FTP:
>   ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY   Could not connect to host
>   'ftp.perl.org' with Net::FTP Fetching with Net::FTP
>   ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY.gz   Could not connect to host
>   'ftp.perl.org' with Net::FTP
>
> Trying with
>       /usr/bin/wget -O "/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459" to get
>       http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY
>   --2015-05-25 16:39:15--  http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY Resolving www.perl.org... 108.161.188.196 Connecting to
>   www.perl.org|108.161.188.196|:80... failed: No route to host.
>
> ```
> Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459"
> ```
>
> "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY" ")
>       returned status 4 (wstat 1024), left /home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459 with size 0
>
> Trying with
>       /usr/bin/wget -O "/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459" to get
>       ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY
>   --2015-05-25 16:39:15--  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY
>              => “/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459” Resolving ftp.perl.org... 130.161.131.20, 131.211.32.146 Connecting to
>   ftp.perl.org|130.161.131.20|:21... failed: No route to host.
>   Connecting to ftp.perl.org|131.211.32.146|:21... failed: No route to
>   host.
>
> ```
> Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459"
> ```
>
> "ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY" ")
>       returned status 4 (wstat 1024), left /home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459 with size 0
>       Warning: no success downloading '/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459'. Giving up on it.
>   No external ftp command available
>
> Fetching with LWP: http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY Fetching with
>   LWP: http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY.gz
>
> Trying with
>       /usr/bin/wget -O "/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459" to get
>       http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY
>   --2015-05-25 16:39:15--  http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY Resolving www.perl.org... 108.161.188.196 Connecting to
>   www.perl.org|108.161.188.196|:80... failed: No route to host.
>
> ```
> Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459"
> ```
>
> "http://www.perl.org/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY" ")
>       returned status 4 (wstat 1024), left /home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459 with size 0
>       Warning: no success downloading '/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459'. Giving up on it.
>   Fetching with LWP: ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY Fetching
>   with LWP: ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY.gz Fetching with
>   Net::FTP: ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY   Could not connect
>   to host 'ftp.perl.org' with Net::FTP Fetching with Net::FTP
>   ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY.gz   Could not connect to host
>   'ftp.perl.org' with Net::FTP
>
> Trying with
>       /usr/bin/wget -O "/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459" to get
>       ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY
>   --2015-05-25 16:39:17--  ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY
>              => “/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459” Resolving ftp.perl.org... 131.211.32.146, 130.161.131.20 Connecting to
>   ftp.perl.org|131.211.32.146|:21... failed: No route to host.
>   Connecting to ftp.perl.org|130.161.131.20|:21... failed: No route to
>   host.
>
> ```
> Function system("/usr/bin/wget -O "/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459"
> ```
>
> "ftp://ftp.perl.org/pub/CPAN/MIRRORED.BY" ")
>       returned status 4 (wstat 1024), left /home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459 with size 0
>       Warning: no success downloading '/home/abashir/.cpan/sources/MIRRORED.BY.tmp33459'. Giving up on it.
>   No external ftp command available
>
> Your urllist is empty! The urllist can be edited. E.g. with 'o conf
>   urllist push ftp://myurl/'
>
> Could not fetch MIRRORED.BY We failed to get a copy of the mirror list
>   from the Internet. You will need to provide CPAN mirror URLs yourself.
>
> Now you can enter your own CPAN URLs by hand. A local CPAN mirror can
>   be listed using a 'file:' URL like 'file:///path/to/cpan/'
>
> CPAN.pm needs at least one URL where it can fetch CPAN files from.
>
> Please enter your CPAN site: []

Then I checked the list of mirrors to in [perlmodlib](https://metacpan.org/pod/perlmodlib) for netherlands(where I live), and I entered them one by one, and configuration was terminated as follows.

> Please enter your CPAN site: [] ftp://ftp.quicknet.nl/pub/CPAN/ Enter
>   another URL or ENTER to quit: [] http://mirror.hostfuss.com/CPAN/
>   Enter another URL or ENTER to quit: [] ftp://mirror.hostfuss.com/CPAN/
>   Enter another URL or ENTER to quit: []
>   http://mirrors3.kernel.org/cpan/ Enter another URL or ENTER to quit:
>   [] ftp://mirrors3.kernel.org/pub/CPAN/ Enter another URL or ENTER to
>   quit: [] http://cpan.mirror.versatel.nl/ Enter another URL or ENTER to
>   quit: [] ftp://ftp.mirror.versatel.nl/cpan/ Enter another URL or ENTER
>   to quit: [] ftp://download.xs4all.nl/pub/mirror/CPAN/ Enter another
>   URL or ENTER to quit: [] http://mirror.leaseweb.com/CPAN/ Enter
>   another URL or ENTER to quit: [] ftp://mirror.leaseweb.com/CPAN/ Enter
>   another URL or ENTER to quit: [] ftp://ftp.cpan.nl/pub/CPAN/ Enter
>   another URL or ENTER to quit: [] http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CPAN/
>   Enter another URL or ENTER to quit: [] ftp://ftp.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CPAN/
>   Enter another URL or ENTER to quit: [] http://luxitude.net/cpan/ Enter
>   another URL or ENTER to quit: []
>
> New urllist
>   ftp://ftp.quicknet.nl/pub/CPAN/   http://mirror.hostfuss.com/CPAN/
>   ftp://mirror.hostfuss.com/CPAN/   http://mirrors3.kernel.org/cpan/
>   ftp://mirrors3.kernel.org/pub/CPAN/   http://cpan.mirror.versatel.nl/ 
>   ftp://ftp.mirror.versatel.nl/cpan/
>   ftp://download.xs4all.nl/pub/mirror/CPAN/
>   http://mirror.leaseweb.com/CPAN/   ftp://mirror.leaseweb.com/CPAN/
>   ftp://ftp.cpan.nl/pub/CPAN/   http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CPAN/
>   ftp://ftp.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CPAN/   http://luxitude.net/cpan/
>
> Autoconfiguration complete.
>
> commit: wrote '/home/abashir/.cpan/CPAN/MyConfig.pm'
>
> You can re-run configuration any time with 'o conf init' in the CPAN
>   shell

Now, whenever I try to install any module, i get errors, for example trying to install [XML::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple), I get the following at the end of trials:

> Please check, if the URLs I found in your configuration file
>   (ftp://ftp.quicknet.nl/pub/CPAN/, http://mirror.hostfuss.com/CPAN/,
>   ftp://mirror.hostfuss.com/CPAN/, http://mirrors3.kernel.org/cpan/,
>   ftp://mirrors3.kernel.org/pub/CPAN/, http://cpan.mirror.versatel.nl/,
>   ftp://ftp.mirror.versatel.nl/cpan/,
>   ftp://download.xs4all.nl/pub/mirror/CPAN/,
>   http://mirror.leaseweb.com/CPAN/, ftp://mirror.leaseweb.com/CPAN/,
>   ftp://ftp.cpan.nl/pub/CPAN/, http://archive.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CPAN/,
>   ftp://ftp.cs.uu.nl/mirror/CPAN/, http://luxitude.net/cpan/) are valid.
>   The urllist can be edited. E.g. with 'o conf urllist push
>   ftp://myurl/'
>
> Could not fetch authors/01mailrc.txt.gz Lockfile removed.

You can check the [Full log](http://jpst.it/z6FP) of the final step [here](http://jpst.it/z6FP)

**How may I solve this ?**

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: You have to configure the proxy. In CPAN shell, use `o conf http_proxy`.

Comment: @choroba, You are GREAT! ... it works finally! Thank you! ... Could you please add it as an answer so that I may mark it up and as solution for your points and for later devs who have same issue  ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be behind a proxy. You have to configure the proxy in CPAN shell:

```
o conf http_proxy 'http://user:password@proxy.com'
```

Answer (score -1):

run cpan shell first:

```
$ sudo perl -MCPAN -eshell
```

or from root:

```
# perl -MCPAN -eshell
```

then from the cpan shell:

```
cpan> install Bundle::CPAN
```

exit from cpan shell and build modules list (maybe need root):

```
$ perl -MCPAN -eautobundle
```

and then install needed modules, for example:

```
# perl -MCPAN -eshell
cpan> notest install Text::Iconv DateTime
```

modules will be installed to /usr/lib64/perl*/ for x86_64 system.